# Help identifying Star Wars and maybe one another set(s)

Tags: set-identification

Got these as a gift.
This is supposedly Star Wars, and maybe one other set, possibly some car.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly some remains of set 75025-1. Guess based on what seems to be four black Technikc Forklift Forks in the last picture...

Comment: A better picture of the top right would help tremendously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top left picture is a fragment of set #9442 "Jay's Storm Fighter".
The top right looks like another fragment of set #9442.
The bottom picture is the base of set #75053 "The Ghost".